# Refactor PySimpleGUI to give pop up to select selenium driver instead of drop down

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pysimplegui

I've built a PySimpleGUI app that selects a CSV,lets you select a Chrome version and then uses Selenium to do form inputs and submits. I now however need to refactor the drop down into a select like how the CSV does but cant get it to work, my code

```
import csv
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):

  try:
# PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
  except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

  return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)



def make_window(theme):

    sg.theme(theme)
    menu_def = [['&Application', ['E&xit']],
                ['&Help', ['&About']] ]
    right_click_menu_def = [[], ['Exit']]

    # Table Data


    input_layout =  [[sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-')],
                 
                
                [sg.Button("Open File")],
               
                [sg.Text('Chrome Version')],

                [sg.OptionMenu(values=('96', '97', '98'),  k='-OPTION MENU-'),],
               
                [sg.Button('Submit')]]



    
    
    layout = [[sg.Text(' Email Automation', size=(38, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 16), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE, k='-TEXT HEADING-', enable_events=True)]]
    layout +=[[sg.TabGroup([[  sg.Tab('Setup CSV and Chrome Version', input_layout),
                               
                               ]], key='-TAB GROUP-')]]
              
    return sg.Window('TEST', layout, right_click_menu=right_click_menu_def)


def main():
    window = make_window(sg.theme())
    
    # This is an Event Loop 
    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening
       
        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
                print(key, ' = ',values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
            print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('TEST email automation',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     'Powered By Me')
        elif event == 'Popup':
            print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
            print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")


        elif event == "Open File":
            print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            csv_file_selected = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            # sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            # print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))




def run_selenium(window, file, driver):

    with open(file, 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Web Automation
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver,service_log_path='/dev/null')
    driver.get('https:/')
  
    
    fname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FIRSTNAME"]')
    lname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LASTNAME"]')
    phone_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PHONE"]')
    mail_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="EMAIL"]')
    deposit_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DEPOSIT"]')
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sib-form"]/div[8]/div/button')

    with open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        next(csv_reader)
        for line in csv_reader:
            
            time.sleep(2.5)
            
            fname_field.send_keys(line[10])
            lname_field.send_keys(line[11])
            mail_field.send_keys(line[13])
            phone_field.send_keys(line[16])
            deposit_field.send_keys(line[37])
            submit.click()
        
        

    # Not to update GUI in thread, but generate an event which will be processed in event loop.
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)

def main():
    # My GUI
    window = make_window(sg.theme())
    folder_or_file = None
    cdriver = resource_path('chromedriver.exe')
    # Using your path for all the drivers of all versions
    paths = {
        #'96': './chromedriver.exe',
        '96': cdriver,
        
    }

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening

        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            # print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            # print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
               print(key, ' = ',values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('email',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     '')
        elif event == 'Popup':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
           # print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")
        elif event == "Open File":
            #print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            folder_or_file = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            # sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            #print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))
        elif event == 'Submit':
            version = values['-OPTION MENU-']
            if folder_or_file is None or version not in paths:
              #  print("No CSV file selected or wrong Chrome version selected")
                continue
            # Using thread to avoid long time job will block and cause GUI no response
            threading.Thread(target=run_selenium, args=(window, folder_or_file, paths[version])).start()
            # Disable Submit button to prevent submit again when threading
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=True)
          #  print('[LOG] Run Selenium ...')
        elif event == 'Done':
            # Enable Submit button when thread done
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=False)
           # print('[LOG] End Selenium')

    window.close()

main()
```

By allowing the chrome version to be picked it will make the whole process much easier instead of consistently rebuilding the app for every new chrome version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the suggestion for version of CromeDriver.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def get_version(file):
    parser = Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    try:
        version = parser.GetFileVersion(file).split(".")[0]
    except Exception:
        version = None
    return version

# It can be read from a json file chromedriver.json for easy update if new version
cromedriver = {
    'explorer': r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    '96': r'.\96\chromedriver.exe',
    '97': r'.\97\chromedriver.exe',
    '98': r'.\98\chromedriver.exe',
}

version = get_version(cromedriver['explorer'])

if version in cromedriver:
    print(Path(cromedriver[version]).absolute())
else:
    print(f'Please download chromedriver.exe for {version} and update chromedriver.json file')
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jason! Is there anyway you could help me with compiling this to an exe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941340/add-additional-files-into-one-file-auto-py-2-exe , Ive tried and tried but it simply will not find the files in one file mode

Comment: I have no idea about the detail to use AutoPy 2 Exe...

Comment: Ah shux alright thanks alot, is there any Python to exe way you know of ?

Comment: What I know are `py2exe` and `pyinstaller`, but not go to detail, just run py file by python.exe or pyw file by pythonw.exe directly.