# Add additional files into one file Auto Py 2 Exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

So I used AutoPy 2 Exe to put a script with additional files into a single executable last year. Now the application needed a second option, added it however after compiling it for the life of me I can't get it to run anymore. The app doesn't do anything after clicking submit. I know last time I had issues with the one-file with additional files.

The files are named: `'97': './chromedriver97.exe'` and I have the recommended code in place

```
def resource_path(relative_path):

  try:
# PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
  except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

  return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Options i used : select file, add files , add logo (works) no result , then tried the same but with the option of path added but still nothing. It simply isn't adding the files.

```
Error from console: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```